# Mini Cooper 2003 - Changed lights to LED, insanely fast indicator lights now

Tags: relay, mini-cooper, led

Changed all the lights on my Girlfriend's Mini Cooper last weekend, since then the indicators have been going crazy (assuming due to power consumption being very low).

I know you can replace the relay for the lights so that it works with LED properly. Do you know what I need to do in order to fix this? I've found these plugs but unsure if I need to replace something that's there or add into a blank slot - http://www.autobulbsdirect.co.uk/LED-Flasher-Unit.html?gclid=CPiKweC03MoCFckaGwodt-8Pow

[image]

**EDIT**

Below is the fuse box and fuse box diagram for reference:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the car have a warning light for a burned out bulb?  LED lights can also make the car think a bulb is burned out unless you use a resistor if your car has such a warning...

Comment: That fuse box diagram is amazing.  You don't know how lucky you are to have that!  My car doesn't even have a list of fuses in the owners manual.

Comment: Haha @JPhi1618 hopefully it will help some others out ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason for this is LEDs don't draw as much power as regular incandescent lights do. By putting the LEDs into the vehicle, you are making the vehicle *believe* the lights are out because of the lower draw. The indicators blink faster to indicate to you, the driver, there is a bulb out which needs to be changed.

One way to fix this is to put a resistor in between the two wires which deliver power to the LED bulb. The resistor will allow for a little more current to pass through back to the blinker relay without causing a short and blowing a fuse. You'll need to look up exactly what you'll need for your application. You might want to start with the manufacturer and ask them what size of resistor is needed.

The relays you have shown in the link are the typical relay plug pattern. If these are the correct pattern for the Cooper (I haven't found the exact one yet), then you can use it without putting a resistor into the wiring at the bulb end. As long as this fits, it's all you'd need to make it work.

Comment: I'll try and get a photo of the fuse box tonight and upload as I'm not sure it actually tells me where it needs to go

Comment: I'm not sure the flasher would be in the fuse box. You probably want to track it down through the "clicking" noise it makes. When you discover where it's at, the clicking should be loud and substantial enough you'll be able to touch the flasher relay and feel it clicking, just so you know you've found it. It may actually be in the fuse box ... but it's always good to know for sure.

Comment: I've updated my question, however i think this might be a weekend job lol

Comment: Did you track the noise as I suggested? Will help you tremendously!

Comment: Not yet, will try tomorrow and work it out hopefully :)

Comment: Found the noise and unfortunately we can't use one of the relay blocks as far as I can tell. Looks like it'll be resistors, which feels like the proper way to do it anyways

Comment: I wish someone would make a small tab you'd put in the base of the socket before you put the bulb in ... one which has the resistor built into it. Would make life *soooo* much more easier. I think some of the bulbs which are little more expensive has the resistor already built into them to prevent such things from happening in the first place.

Comment: Any ideas where I could get those from?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but in the off chance someone else is looking for the answer, new Mini Coopers do not have a flasher relay. The flashers are controlled by the BCM.  You will need to wire in the resistor to cure the fast flash issue.